# Normalisation and .TIFF format

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, normalization

I'm currently using OpenCV (in C++) to normalize some data in the form of images. Since I'm planning to train an autoencoder I found some articles and papers suggesting that it's better if the data is normalised in the range from -1 to 1 (tanh vs sin). I managed to do this with the following code:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(video);
cv::Mat frame;
cap.read(frame);

//convert to grayscale
cv::cvtColor(*frame, *frame, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

//normalise
frame->convertTo(*frame, CV_32FC1); //change data type from CV_8UC1 to CV_32FC1
cv::normalize(*frame, *frame, -1, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);

//downscale
cv::resize(*frame, *frame, cv::Size(256, 256));
```

The next thing I want to do is to save the normalised image and for this I'm using `cv::imwrite()`, so I have the following line: `cv::imwrite("normImage.tiff", *frame);`.

I'm wondering, however, if writing the image to .TIFF format actually reverses the normalisation and I haven't been able to verify whether that's the case or not. I'd also like to ask if there's a better way/format to write the image using OpenCV?

Cheers

Comment: I hear that TIFF can hold 32-bit float data. if you're lucky, nothing clips these values in any way. -- imwrite your data, imread it, compare. is it still the same? -- if you use C++, I don't think there's a more suitable format for arrays. you could use OpenCV's `FileStorage`, which uses yaml or something, but that'll just blow up because it's text

Comment: TIFF can store floating point values, but very few TIFF readers and writers support that. The implementation in [DIPlib](https://diplib.org/) does (I write it). You could also just write your pixel values directly to a binary file, keep it very simple. Since you are standardizing the size also, you know that every 256*256*4 bytes are one image.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried reading the image, which I have created:
```
cv::Mat test;
test.create(cv::Size(256, 256), CV_32FC1);
test =cv::imread(name, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```
but for some reason it gives me this exception: `cv::TiffDecoder::readData OpenCV TIFF: TIFFRGBAImageOK: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples`. I didn't expect this to happen, since there is a note in the documentation of `cv::imread`, which says that "On Windows, the codecs shipped with an OpenCV image (libjpeg, libpng, libtiff, and libjasper) are used by default. So, OpenCV can always read TIFFs.".

Comment: @CrisLuengo I might give your library a shot if I can't verify the work of OpenCV. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Update, turns out I just had to use `cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED`. The output seems fine, so I guess I will continue like this. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You can also write 32-bit floats to PFM files, btw, which can be read/written by **ImageMagick**.